# When integrating, can only one term of an equation be integrated or must entire equation be integrated to maintain equality?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Is integration considered a basic operation in the sense you have to do it to all parts of the equation?

$y dy - x dx = 0$
Is it valid to do
$\int y dy - \int x dx = \int 0$
but invalid to leave out a term, for example
$\int y dy - x dx = \int 0$
So do you need to integrate all terms of both sides of the equation?
I find it a little strange because the integration operation may have different integrands so it acts differently e.g. integrating with respect to $y$ instead of $x$.

In other words does integration work the same way as as any other algebra, like squaring both sides of the equation?

Comment: What you do to one *side* of the equation, you must do to the other *side*.

Comment: @JohnD write, but the variable being integrated with respect to can be different?

Answer (score 2):

First, a *quick but very important warning*:

In basic calculus, the symbol combination

$$ydy - x dx = 0$$

does not really make sense. It is a dirty trick because it is the quickest way of transforming

$$y\frac{dy}{dx} - x = 0,$$

which is a differential equation, into $$\int ydy - \int xdx = 0,$$

which is the next step in solving the differential equation.

---

That said, yes, when you pull off this dirty little trick, you must always add integrals to all elements which have a $dx$ or $dy$ sign.

---

Further explanation:

I am trying to say that usually, what happens is this:

1. You get a task: solve the differential equation $\frac{dy}{dx} y - x = 0$
2. You solve the task in two steps. In the first step, you write down $ydy - xdx =0$
3. In the second step, you "integrate" what you wrote down and get $\int ydy - \int xdx  = 0$.
4. You solve the integrals and extract $y=y(x)$.

In this sequence of steps, writing down $ydy - xdx = 0$ is a step which is *technically not correct* because the expression $dy$ by itself is not defined, it only makes sense if it is written either in an integral (so $\int ydy$ is well defined) or in a derivative (so $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is well defined). However, the intermediary step (step 2) is a useful trick for rewriting equation (1) into equation (3).

Comment: Not sure I follow. So you're saying often times the step $y\frac{dy}{dx} - x = 0$ is skipped?

Comment: @Celeritas Not at all. I am saying that the places where you encounter the "expression" $ydy-xdx=0$ are those places where you are really trying to solve $y\frac{dy}{dx}-x=0$, and the solution is found by solving the integrals $\int ydy - \int xdx = 0$. The intermediary step, $ydy - xdx = 0$, is just a dirty trick to get you across.

Comment: $ydy-xdx=0$ is the same as $\int ydy - \int xdx = 0$ so what do you mean by "what we're really trying to solve"?

Comment: @Celeritas In a way, no, $ydy - xdx$ is not the same as $\int ydy - \int xdx$, because the second expression is well defined, but the first one isn't. See the edit I made in my answer for a more extensive explanation.

Comment: Correction, you need an integral on the zero term. As in: $\int ydy-\int xdx=\boldsymbol{\int 0}$. To the OP: The integral of zero is a constant, and all the constants of integration get "swallowed up" into one, as in: $\frac{y^2}{2}+C_y+\frac{x^2}{2}+C_x=C_1 \rightarrow \frac{y^2+x^2}{2}=C$.